# Error in OpenVpn android app

Tags: android, openvpn

I have downloaded the openvpn code from 
https://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/source/checkout
and it compile succesfully but when I create a profile and try to connect it .. it will give me an error "Error writing minivpn binary "

the readme file says
Optional: Copy minivpn from lib/ to assets (if you want your own compiled version)

but I havent found any minivpn or lib like this in the package 
please let me know if some has worked on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the README:

> Do ./build-native.sh in the root directory of the project.

The minivpn part is obsolete. Early version used to ship a compiled version in the repository.

Comment: I am not getting it ? Do ./build-native.sh I have tried it through cmd but it gives me an error can you elaborate it ?

Comment: Have you really read the whole README? Especially the part about installing an Android NDK. Your error messages is probably that ndk-build cannot be found.

Comment: yes I have read it and installed the ndk as well and tried to build it  :/ but still I guess I am doing it wrong can you please tell me how can I build it through ndk ..

Comment: Should should post the error message you are getting when trying to build it.

Comment: its building perfectly fine .. I am getting this error on connecting openvpn .. its showing in the log file of openvpn

Comment: Check your apk if it really includes the files. Refresh your work tree/clean your build in Eclipse. I have multiple reports of people having build ics-openvpn from source. Trust me, it works.

Comment: I hvae done it through batch file .. I dont know what was the issue but there might be somthing which is causing this .. the project is working fine and the instruction given in Readme is perfect .

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue, can you please elaborate your steps?